Git/Github: fixing repos history
I have this repos on GitHub:

[user 1] original
[user 2] copy(original)
\ -> [ME]  fork(copy(original))

copy has added some commits on top of original, and my fork has other commits on top of copy (chronologically sequential, there is no time overlapping between repos)
I want to preserve the structure of the forks in order to put, in the future, my commits to original, like making a fork of original, then add to it the copy commits, then add the fork commits, preserving the authors of them and hopefully also the timestamps. Something like this:

[user 1] original
\ -> [ME] fork(original) <-- but with the commits that user 2 has on his own copy(original), and my commits on top of them

Is there a way to do this?

To clarify: You wish to make a fork of the original that has the commits of User 2's fork? What's wrong with making a fork of User 2's repo, like it is currently?

If you want to "put your commits to original" you can always make a PR from your fork to the original, no matter what repo its forked from.

Hi, thanks for your comment. Your interpretation is correct except for the fact that user 2 does not have a fork, but a copy (i.e., literally copy-paste of user 1's files) of the original user 1's repo, with user 2's subsequent commits on top of them. The reason of my will to make this sort of tree is that in the future my commits will be pushed to the original repo, along with user 2's ones, but this cannot happen now because user 2 does not have a fork, but a copy, so pull requests cannot be done.

Odd behavior from User 2. Potentially, you could fork User 1's repo, and then paste in the files from User 2's repo, but new commits wouldn't be automatically downloaded.

Yeah, pretty odd. By the way, I also think forking User 1's repo, as also you suggest, is the main path to follow, but is there for sure no way to make User 2's commits appear in some way into the commit list?

Did User 2 copy only the files, or did they copy the history?  Even though they did not fork User 1's repository, they may still have taken the history (cloned User 1's repository and pushed to User 2's repository) and made commits on top. You should clarify that, because then the case becomes simple. But if they didn't copy the history (but only the files at a particular state), you are in for a bit of work.

Hi, thanks for your comment, and sorry for my late answer. User 2 just copied the files, a literal Ctrl-C + Ctrl-V. So no trace of the User 1 history outside of the original repo.
